# Bootstrap Carousel jumps in height

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a `react-bootstrap` carousel.

It jumps when it scrolls because the images have different sizes, but if I give them the size `weight: 1309px` and `height: 730px` - I lose the responsiveness and on every device there is only `730px` of `height` and it doesn't resize to be responsive.

How can I fix it to have the same size of every picture (don't allow carousel to jump) and maintain responsiveness?

Look at the pictures, and how arrows jump in a different height:

![Bootstrap Carousel Screenshot][1]

Here is my code:

```html
<div id="carousel-container">
  <Carousel>
    <Carousel.Item>
      <img src={firstImg} />
      <Carousel.Caption>
        <h3>Niagara Falls</h3>
        <p>One of the most famous wonders of nature is Niagara Falls.</p>
      </Carousel.Caption>
    </Carousel.Item>
    <Carousel.Item>
      <img src={secondImg} />
      <Carousel.Caption>
        <h3>Monuments Valley</h3>
        <p>Monument Valley is a region of the Colorado Plateau characterized by a cluster of vast sandstone buttes.</p>
      </Carousel.Caption>
    </Carousel.Item>
    <Carousel.Item>
      <img src={thirdImg} />
      <Carousel.Caption>
        <h3>Grand Canyon</h3>
        <p>The Grand Canyon is a famous canyon in Arizona.</p>
      </Carousel.Caption>
    </Carousel.Item>
  </Carousel>
</div>
```

Comment: Please could you include your CSS?

Comment: `#carousel-container {
    margin-top: -20px;
    border: 1px solid #c2e1f5;
}

#carousel-container img{
    /* height: 730px; */
    width: 1309px;
}`

Comment: Dude you removed the screenshot with your edit! Please include all relevant CSS (with the media queries too) in the snippet in your post :)

Comment: It's the only styles for carousel I have, others are from bootstrap(including media-queries)

Comment: Try giving all the images same width and height and then add object-fit: cover; to all the img tag

Comment: Wow, it helped, thanks, but height doesn't resize when you change your screen size, it stays constant every time

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `className="d-block w-100"` into your `<img />` tag. And... if this don't work, tray use another image with more height!